# Is it necessary to mount ESP at boot?

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, uefi, automount

I recently dual-booted my laptop, installing Ubuntu 16.04 beside an existing install of Windows 7 (on separate hard disks).  For convenience/curiosity, I also spent some time messing around with files and settings until I could boot the Ubuntu install as a VM in VirtualBox with raw disk access.  In order to do this, I had to create an ESP on the second hard disk with copies of the Ubuntu files from the original ESP, and well as removing (commenting out) the fstab entry that mounted the primary/original ESP (without commenting it out, VM Ubuntu would only boot into recovery mode).

My main question is whether not mounting the (any) ESP could cause issues with programs expecting it to be there etc. (I ran apt upgrade earlier today and it printed that if found and updated files on /dev/sda1 (the original ESP))

The second question is whether having 2 separate ESPs could break updates etc. Right now the /EFI/ubuntu/* files are copied exactly, including grub.cfg which just points to /boot/grub.cfg anyway.  I'm trying to be careful not to run any updates while booted as a VM, but accidentally started one earlier today and CTRL-C'ed it to stop.

Basically, I've hacked/googled my way to a system that works but I want to make sure that I haven't broken important things along the way.

Comment: the only thing using the ESP is grub

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be mounted for any updates to grub to install properly.  That's about all.  Similarly, if you have two of them only one will be updated ( the one that is mounted ) when grub is updated.